# Как связать input с textarea?

Tags: html, вёрстка, text, textarea

Как связать `<input type="text">` с `<textarea>`?

К примеру:

Есть поле `<textarea>`, он уже заполнен скажем этим (этот текст то что внутри `textarea=500`).
Ниже есть поле `<input type="text">` внутри заполнен (500).
Как сделать так, чтобы если я пишу какую либо цифру внутри `<input type="text">` к примеру 700, то он бы заменял 500 который внутри `<textarea>` и оно стало таким  (это то что внутри `textarea=700`)?

Comment: C помощью JavaScript (как вариант - JQuery) подписываетесь на событие keypress (или как его там) первого контрола и в функции, обрабатывающей это событие копируете содержимое первого контрола во второй

Answer (score 2):

Код html:

```
  <input class="input" type="text" value=""/>
  <textarea class="textarea" rows="3" cols="10">700</textarea>
```

Код jQuery, после загрузки страницы:

```
 var $textarea = $(".textarea");
 $(document).on('keyup','.input', function(){
     $textarea.text($(this).val());
 });
```

То же самое на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/genson/sKnhv/)

**UPDATE:** [Обновил пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/genson/sKnhv/2/) Теперь есть часть текста, которая не меняется.